# Why does the Japanese version of Mushrambo/Shinzo start at episode 2?

Tags: anime-production, mushrambo

I am currently watching Mushrambo/Shinzo (the Japanese version), and the series starts at episode 2.

The English version of the anime has a different beginning. Why is that?

Comment: This seems like it might be an issue with whatever VHS/DVD/etc you're watching this on. Nothing I can find suggests that the Japanese version skips episode 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The English version does things chronologically, blending and splicing a lot of events together that were left as flash backs in the Japanese version into the beginning of the English version. So the Japanese one does kinda start at "episode 2", throwing you directly into the action and getting to the boring bits later, at least to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

There was actually a different episode 1 dub when it aired on Fox Kids in Australia, which was the first episode in the Japanese one. For some reason, one of the companies may have lost the first real episode 1 english dub and created that patched together Jetix episode to replace it.